# How to create multiple attachments with same name in Lotus notes using c++ api?

Tags: lotus-notes, email-attachments

I am trying to create multiple attachments with same name using api

```
lndocument doc;
lnstring atchmntpath;
lnstring atchmntname;
lnattachment att;
doc.createattachment(atchmntpath,atchmntname,FALSE,&att);
```

while creating 2nd attachment with the existing attachment name,the api returns error.can anyone help how to create the 2nd attachment with already existing attachment name in document;

Comment: Why should one want that? Is this even legal with the definition of email attachments? I would never want to receive such an email, even less I want to send one.

Comment: I doubt there is a way. If you do manage to find a way, though, the Domino back-end will most likely rename on of the attachments internally to "ATT0001". We see that type of behavior in various Domino contexts.